# fetch two rows with one id in linq to sql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

im new to linq to sql. my query is about fetch two more rows with one site number using the search button.There is a link between the tables using foreign key.
Let me clear the database which look like.

Hi,

I have Four tables tbl_user, tbl_Site,tbl_usersite and tbl_credentials.

**Table columns:**

- tbl_Site          : SiteId, SiteName, SiteNumb
- tbl_Credentials   : CredId, Username,Password
- tbl_User          : UserId, CredIdFK, Forename , Surname
- tbl_Usersite      : UsersiteID, Site_IdFK, User_IdFk

**Table relationship:**

- (tbl_Usersite) table is to link the table (tbl_User and tbl_Site)
- In tbl_user table Cred_Id is the FK

**Site sample data:**

SiteId, SiteName, SiteNumb

- 10 , XXXX , 1234
- 11 , YYYY , 5436
- 12 , ZZZZ , 3789

**Credentials Sample data:**

CredId, Username, Password

- 10,  google, yahoo
- 11,  Blog , Forum
- 12,  Date , Time
- 13,  Linq , Sql
- 14,  Total , Cost

**User sample data:**

UserId, CredId, Forename, Surname

- 187 , 10 , Sarah , Thomas
- 196 , 11 , Mark , Hill
- 195 , 12 , Peter, Hodge
- 197 , 13 , Brad , Pitt
- 198 , 14 , Brown , Thomas

**Usersite sample data:**

UsersiteId , SiteId , UserId

- 1 , 10 , 187
- 2 , 10 , 196
- 3 , 10 , 195
- 4 , 11 , 197
- 5 , 12 , 198

The Client Enter the SiteNumber in the textBox and by clicking the search button. They should get **Username , Password, UserId, ForeName and Surname**. and my sample code in the button click event is

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string Site = txtsitenumb.Text;

    SiteDataContext sitenumb = new SiteDataContext();

     try
        {
            var siteID = (from sn in sitenumb.tbl_sites
                       where sn.site_number == Site
                       select sn.site_id_PK).First();

             var UserID = (from sn2 in sitenumb.tbl_usersites
                      **where sn2.usersite_site_id_FK == siteID
                         select  sn2.usersite_user_id_FK).First();**

             // Where the Star Marked area doesnt give the result
                if there is an access for more than one Site for the single User

             var CredID = (from sn3 in sitenumb.tbl_users
                       where sn3.user_id_PK == UserID
                       select sn3.user_credentials_id_FK).First();

            var UserName = (from sn4 in sitenumb.tbl_credentials
                            where sn4.credentials_id_PK == CredID 
                            select sn4.credentials_username).First();

            var PassWord = (from sn5 in sitenumb.tbl_credentials
                            where sn5.credentials_id_PK == CredID 
                            select sn5.credentials_password).First();

            var FirstName = (from sn6 in sitenumb.tbl_users
                             where sn6.user_id_PK == UserId 
                             select sn6.user_forename).First();

            var Lastname = (from sn7 in sitenumb.tbl_users
                            where sn7.user_id_PK == UserId 
                            select sn7.user_surname).First();



            fields s = new fields();
            s.UserName = UserName;
            s.Password = PassWord;
            s.UserId = UserID .ToString();
            s.FirstName = FirstName;
            s.LastName = Lastname;


                data.Add(s);
                ViewState["idata"] = data;

                gridview1.DataSource = data;
                gridview1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label1.Text = "File Not Found";

        }   


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnsearch.UniqueID;


        data = ViewState["idata"] as List<fields>;
        if (data == null)
            data = new List<fields>();


}
[Serializable]
public class fields
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }

}
```

This code works fine if it is Single Site access for Single User. Please help me to display the User associate with all the sites.

** For Example:**

If the user enters SiteNumb 1234(Siteid 10). It has to display all the Three(UserId: 187,196,195) users details.. please reply ASAP..

Many Thanks

Comment: ASAP since you say `.First()` it gets you that, How do you want to display it (like concatenate them ?? ) i guess you should be handling a list of the values and then filter out on base of your needs many or only one

Comment: u r getting UserId using First(), that will give you only one UserId...

Comment: You could use .ToList() which will return all the relevant results.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton Thanks for the reply. if i use the .Tolist()   'var credID = (from sn3 in sitenumb.tbl_users
                           where **sn3.user_id_PK == UserID**
                           select sn3.user_credentials_id_FK).First();'  Cant use the Userid in the next statement to fetch the credentials ID.

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks for the reply. S i need to display watever the user associate with the site(s)(many or one).

Comment: @GopeshSharma Thanks for ur reply.. if i use the .Tolist(); i couldn't use the Userid to fetch username and password stuffs..

Comment: why can't u write one more query calling UserIds where you can use .ToList() to get all the user's ids?

Comment: @GopeshSharma Thanks. Will u please assist me with the code how u want me to use.. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you use joins on these queries rather than multiple queries, it looks like they've got relationships right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have shown your database entries,there may be more than one users having access on a particular site.`.First()`  return the single row.Therefore you should modify your code to get the list by using `ToList()` method.

For example, you can modify the code to get all users for the particular site id as:-

```
 var UserID = (from sn2 in sitenumb.tbl_usersites
                      where sn2.usersite_site_id_FK == siteID
                         select  sn2.usersite_user_id_FK).ToList();
```

you can modify your code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

```
var UserID = (from sn2 in sitenumb.tbl_usersites
             where sn2.usersite_site_id_FK == siteID
             select  sn2.usersite_user_id_FK).First();
//Here you will get only single UserId
var UserIds = (from sn2 in sitenumb.tbl_usersites
              where sn2.usersite_site_id_FK == siteID
              select  sn2.usersite_user_id_FK).ToList() 
// Here you will get all the UserIds of that particular site
```